# Tomcat cannot start after bad war file

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I deployed a war file to my Apache Tomcat 9 server using the tomcat web manager, the application was having issues so I restarted the server. I noticed that the server does not boot due to some errors for the war file.

I deleted the project folder and the war file under /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps

But when I try to start Tomcat, it still tries to find the project I have deleted.

```
[2019-05-08 23:21:18] [crit] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/myproject] is not valid
[2019-05-08 23:21:18] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:749)
[2019-05-08 23:21:18] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:706)
[2019-05-08 23:21:18] [crit]     at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
[2019-05-08 23:21:18] [crit]     ... 30 more
[2019-05-08 23:21:18] [info] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
[2019-05-08 23:21:18] [info] Stopping service [Catalina]
[2019-05-08 23:21:18] [info] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
```

What can I do to fully get rid of the project in Tomcat so I can make it boot up again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had a virtual host pointing to the application. I commented it and tomcat booted up